# Can I file search the entire Windows domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, search

Servers:  Windows 2008r2.  Workstations:  Windows 7 Pro.

My company runs MasterCAM as it's 2D CAM package on the shop floor.  We are in the process of planning an x6 to x9 upgrade.  One of our problems is the disorganization of Tool Libraries on the 20 or so workstations that run the software.  We'd like to combine all these employee Tool Libraries into one company library.  The extension of the file is unique but in different locations on each workstation.  Instead of having to map and search each individual c$ share, is it possible to submit a single search that will find all the files with that extension in our Windows domain?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing but maybe someone wiser than I will answer yes and how. If not, you can probably write or find a PowerShell script that will do this.

Comment: This should work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336359/powershell-script-to-search-for-file-types-from-a-list-of-machines-then-copy-re

Comment: There are probably a bazillion third party utilities and programs that can do this. Here's one of them - https://www.softperfect.com/products/lspro/